# Difference between "is like nothing else" and "is not like anything else"

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

"Anyone who has visited Paris knows that this city is not like anything else"

"Anyone who has visited Paris knows that this city is like nothing else"

Is there any difference between these two sentences, and which one is the most appropriate variant?

Comment: Apart from the act that the shorter form is [***much more common***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=not+like+anything+else%2Clike+nothing+else&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cnot%20like%20anything%20else%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clike%20nothing%20else%3B%2Cc0), I can't see any scope for any difference in meaning. The "less common" form isn't so unusual that anyone would normally notice it, so they wouldn't be left wondering why you chose *not* to use the more common version.

Comment: No difference at all. _None/Nothing_ are just the negative and the determiner contracted -- same difference as _It's_ versus _It is_, i.e, zero.